# How do I create a file to open many different Chrome Browser websites at once on OS 10.13.6

Tags: macos, scripting

MacOS 10.13.6 Chrome Version 77.0.3865.90
I would like to open 20 different Facebook Group Pages with Chrome (I Do Not EVER Use Safari) with a "batch" file. I know that's a 'Windows' term but that's all I know...

Here's What I Do Now:
Once the Chrome Browser is up, I can open them one at a time from 'Notes' with all the links in one file and then clicking on one link, then click back to notes and click on the next link... 
I'd like to save a lot of Daily labor by creating a desktop file I can click on to open them all at once...

I have 41 different groups I use but on my system Chrome can open 20 at a time without a lot of 'WAIT' Time...

I'm REALLY IGNORANT! All the Experience I have is DOS 3.1, from the 1980s-90s I hope one of You WIZARDS can help me with this problem...
Note: I Tried to post what I know how to do but the system won't allow me to put it in since it's now BAD Code(Example I know...Start “facebook-1” www.facebook.com/The Holy Bible).
Thanx HEAPS!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

I would say the most user-friendly way to achieve this is using Apples build in Automator App.

Here is what I did:

1. Create a new Automator Program.
2. I added a "Get Specified URLs" block. Here you can add all the websites you want to open up.
3. Then I added a "Run Shell Script" block that contains the code to open up Chrome for every url you entered above. Just make sure to pick "As Argument" in the top right of the block.

Once saved all your websites should open up at once.

[image: Automator Screenshot]
My system language is set to german but you should be fine to follow along.